# Merging duplicate DOMParser tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

I just noticed that there's a tag [domparser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/domparser) and [dom-parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom-parser), so since there's no point in having both, I'd like to request the latter to be changed to a tag synonym of the former. It has no tag wiki anyway, so I'm assuming it was just accidentally made by someone who didn't bother to look if the tag already existed.

Comment: There's only 11 questions. You could just retag them all and it would be automatically burninated.

Comment: @bjb568 it says "36 questions tagged" for me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dom-parser.

Comment: Ugh. I was on the unanswered tab, apparently. Yeah, a synonym might be better then.